# Ionic 3 + One Signal handleNotificationReceived doesn't get fired

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

I'm following [this Ionic SDK Setup link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup). I'm setting up the push notification on my app.

It's working, I can get the notification. Here's my code.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    let OneSignal = window["plugins"].OneSignal;

    OneSignal
      .startInit(AppSettings.ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
      .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
      .handleNotificationOpened(function(jsonData) {
        console.log('OPENED');
      })
      .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonData) {
        console.log('RECEIVED');
      })
      .endInit();

    OneSignal.getIds(notificationsCallBack.getIdReceived.bind(this));
});
```

However, the function handleNotificationReceived is only called if the app is open. I need to execute some code (I need an in-app badge), even if the app is closed. I'm setting the `content_available to true` on my OneSignal API, I also tested directly on the OneSignal website and I couldn't make it works. The function handleNotificationOpened works as expected.

How can I handle the notification received event when my app is not open?

I'm testing on iPhone 6+, iOS 11.0.3

My env:

`Ionic 3.12.0
Cordova 7.0.1`

My package.json

```
{
    "name": "XXX",
    "author": "XXXX XX",
    "homepage": "XXX",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/core": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/forms": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/http": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.2",
        "@angular/router": "^4.2.2",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.3.1",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.2.2",
        "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^3.2.2",
        "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/toast": "^3.10.3",
        "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.2.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.0",
        "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.5.1",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.7",
        "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.7.4",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.0.11",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git",
        "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.6.0",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
        "cropperjs": "^1.1.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
        "ionic-native": "2.9.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.5.0-beta",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ios-sim": "^6.1.2",
        "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.4",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.0.11",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
        "cordova-plugin-compat",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer",
        "cordova-plugin-file"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [
        {
            "platform": "ios",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "ios"
        },
        {
            "platform": "android",
            "version": "",
            "locator": "android"
        }
    ],
    "description": "ion2-FullApp: The Best Ionic 2 Starter app",
    "config": {
        "ionic_sass": "./config/sass.config.js",
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "platforms": [
            "ios"
        ],
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "XX",
                "APP_NAME": "XXX"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
                "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "XX"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
                "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "XX",
                "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "XX",
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Show your location on the map",
                "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Trace your location on the map",
                "key": "XX"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get the notification when app is close ??

Comment: You can't. Your code won't execute unless the app is in foreground.

Comment: @KishanOza The notification opened event was fixed in the OneSignal Cordova SDK 2.2.0. It was only an issue for iOS 11 devices.

Comment: But i am testing on android device still didn't get @eugeniobac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification opened event was fixed in the OneSignal Cordova SDK 2.2.0. It was only an issue for iOS 11 devices.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check [this](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/257#issuecomment-480588116). Let me know if it works for you.
You need to set content_available and mutable_content in true in the body of the POST request.

Comment: Given link  can be useful , but its better to describe some useful information in the answer.